# How to count pipes from the image?

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I would like to count objects (pipes) from this photo:

[image: Pipes image]

Can you help me and give me a general idea of how it should be done? I'm still a beginner and have no previous experience in processing images like this. I've googled it and found something called OpenCv but couldn't go anywhere from there.

Comment: you can use [HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) function look at [Hough Circle Transform Tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html#gsc.tab=0)

Answer (score 2):

If the pipes are always red - take only the red channel from the RGB image.

Have you tried hough transform? It will detect the circles (pipe holes).
You can tweak it a bit to detect elipses as well.

Another approach is to invert the colors of the image and use connected components analysis. The dark holes surrounded with brigth color is an excelent feature

You can also train a classifier on the red channel. Try built in openCV boosted detectors (should be relatively good even with HAAR features. Look at the example of training face detectors. openCV has all the code ready. You just have to cut manually examples of pipe holes.

Comment: Did you notice the red item in the background upper middle right? It has a grey area in the centre but it is not a pipe. Your algorithm will have to filter that out. Also, some of the pipes' bright rims are partially obscured by neighouring pipes. Don't filter them out.

Comment: Hough transform can detects circles/elipses even when they are partially occluded. Same goes for the detector (HAAR classifier). If you use connected component just filter out small components (very small holes)